# Can I retrofit heated side mirrors if it wasn't an option with the car?

Tags: opel, agila, aftermarket-upgrade, mirrors

Is it possible for me to add heated mirrors to my car, if it wasn't an option at all as standard? I would like to keep the mirrors standard.

My mirrors on my 2003 Opel Agila are a really awkward shape, which do not let ice scrapers fit inside properly, and de-icer spray just freezes after a few minutes.

Is there an aftermarket kit which allows me to make the mirrors heated without changing the actual mirror? I'm willing to do extra wiring, and at a last resort change the glass.

EDIT: It is not an option on any model of the Agila, or the identical Wagon R+

Comment: Any idea if your car had heated mirrors as an option?

Comment: @JPhi1618. It is not an option at all

Comment: This is just speculation, so not an answer, but I have seen "windshield wiper heater" kits.  They stick to the inside of the windshield to warm the wiper area.  Something like that _might_ be modified to work on the mirrors.

Comment: I would try to find heated mirrors from a different type of car, and try to fit them on yours. And of course, you'll still have to figure out the wiring.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

http://www.ebay.com/bhp/mirror-heater

that should bring ya to the page, they aren't that much, around 15 bucks.

Answer (score 2):

The only way to get heated mirrors is to buy the mirrors separately, but there is although a product that is a heated pad to place on the back of your mirror, although you will have to have wiring done to turn them on and put them on a switch, which is really not that big of a problem.